# Comparison of different statistical tests on different amount of biological replicates

Tags: t-test, negative-binomial-distribution, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, hypothesis-testing

I am testing differentially expressed genes using different statistical tests on different amount of biological replicates (Wilcoxon test, t-test and negative binomial test). Figure below is what I got.

[image: This].

My questions are:

1: Why the No. of DEG decreases when replicates reach to 500?

2: Why Negative binomial test detect less DEG than other two tests?

Does this trend make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of guessing here:

> 1: Why the No. of DEG decreases when replicates reach to 500?

The difference between 100 and 500 is not much and it may be explained by random sampling. If you try different samples for N=100 and N=500, do you still see the same picture?

> 2: Why Negative binomial test detect less DEG than other two tests?

Negative binomial allows extra variation in addition to random sampling from a Poisson distribution and this should make it more conservative compared to t and Wilcox tests, especially if the data is close to normally distributed and underdispersed compared to a Poisson.

Here's a simple simulation of 1000 genes, 10 replicates per condition, true difference is 50 vs 52. Data comes from a normal distribution with standard deviation 5:

```r
library(data.table)
library(MASS)

N <- 1000
nb <- rep(NA, N)
wx <- rep(NA, N)
tt <- rep(NA, N)
alldat <- list()
for(i in 1:N) {
    if(i %% 100 == 0) {
        print(i)
    }
    n <- 10
    set.seed(i)
    dat <- data.table(
        cond= rep(c('A', 'B'), each= n),
        cnt= round(c(rnorm(n= n, mean= 50, sd= 5), rnorm(n= n, 
                           mean= 52, sd= 5))),
        i= i
    )
    smry <- summary(glm.nb(cnt ~ cond, data = dat))
    nb[i] <- smry$coefficients[2, 4]
wx[i] <- wilcox.test(dat[cond == 'A']$cnt, 
                             dat[cond == 'B']$cnt)$p.value
    tt[i] <- t.test(dat[cond == 'A']$cnt, 
                    dat[cond == 'B']$cnt)$p.value
    dat[, nb:= nb[i]]
    dat[, wx :=wx[i]]
    dat[, tt :=tt[i]]
    alldat[[length(alldat) + 1]] <- dat
}
alldat <- rbindlist(alldat)
sum(nb < 0.01) # 3 genes with p < 0.01
sum(wx < 0.01) # 32
sum(tt < 0.01) # 36
```

If you replace `sd= 5` with `sd= 8`, thus making the data more dispersed, negbin model is more powerful than the others:

```r
sum(nb < 0.01)
[1] 30
sum(wx < 0.01)
[1] 17
sum(tt < 0.01)
[1] 18
```

Maybe this helps to explain your results?

Comment: Can I understand as that, comparing with t-test and Wilcoxon, negative Binomial correctly model dispersed variance of data (the data indeed own dispersed variance) and  these dispersed distributions of two groups being tested get more 'overlap'. Therefore negative Binomial correctly reject more result (as shown in figure above). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: However, why does negative Binomial test yielded more significant results than other two tests when you expand SD?

Comment: I was surprised myself to see that expanding SD makes things "better" for the negbin. I think it is because with larger SD you get more chances of extreme datasets across 1000 replicates. These extreme datasets are correctly picked up by negbin but the orther tests reject them as they are overdispersed (although Wilcox test is non-parametric and so it does not make assumptions about the dispersion). I edited the R code to save the simulated results in variable `alldat` in case you want to inspect the results